small whitespace at the bottom
I am creating my website using html and bulma but I noticed that there is small whitespace at the bottom of my page.


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/1.0.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="columns">
  <aside class="menu has-background-primary is-fullheight">
    <p class="menu-label has-text-white is-size-1 ">LOGO</p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li>
        <p class="menu-item has-background-primary mb-6 "><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-user fa-4x icon is-large mr-4 has-text-white"></i><span class="text has-text-white is-size-1">Amiel</span></p>
      </li>
      <li><a href="./adminDash.php" class="menu-item has-background-primary mt-6"><i class="fa-solid fa-chart-line fa-2x icon is-large mr-4 has-text-white"></i><span class="text has-text-white is-size-4">Dashboard</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="./adminStudents.php" class="menu-item has-background-primary mt-6"><i class="fa-solid fa-graduation-cap fa-2x icon is-large mr-4 has-text-white"></i><span class="text has-text-white is-size-4">Students</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="./adminTeachers.php" class="menu-item has-background-primary mt-6"><i class="fa-solid fa-chalkboard-user fa-2x icon is-large mr-4 has-text-white"></i><span class="text has-text-white is-size-4">Teachers</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu-item has-background-primary mt-6"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket fa-2x icon is-large mr-4 has-text-white"></i><span class="text has-text-white is-size-4">Logout</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>



I have tried 100vh on columns, div, and aside. added padding:0 and margin: 0 in my body tag but nothing happens please help
edit: It is solved now, thanks to @Paulie_D I used margin-top: 0 in .columns

Appears to be a Bulma setting for .columns - margin-top: calc(var(--bulma-column-gap)* -1); - Try using margin-top: 0.

@Paulie_D Thank you, for that, I have been trying to solve it using margin-bottom: 0.

thanks @MisterJojo for suggesting on how to ask good question, will take your advice into considerations in my next question.

That's why we inspect the code (F12) or right-click "inspect" and we can turn properties on and off or change values to see what happens.

The source of this whitespace area is bulma.css.
For CSS selector .columns:not(:last-child) it sets the margin-bottom: calc(var(--bulma-block-spacing) - var(--bulma-column-gap)) style.
Just set margin-bottom value for this selector to value you wish to use (0 probably) - that's it.
